# Display Select2 value not in list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, jquery-select2

While a new value may be added to the Select2 (3.5) element using createSearchChoice, how can I get a new value to display if it is not in the list?  I can add values not in the Select2 list, but how would a default value not in the list be displayed?

```
$("#select").select2({
    placeholder: "Who is the invoice from?",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    quietMillis: 300,
    allowClear : true,
    ajax: {
        url: "accountsDataStore.xsp",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, // search term
                page_limit: 10
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) { return data; }
    },

    // extra code to allow entering value not in list
    id: function(object) { return object.text; },

    //Allow manually entered text in drop down.
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
                        if ( $(data).filter( function() {
                                  return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;
                              }).length===0) {
                                      return {id:term, text:term};
                        }
    },

    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                        //sets a default value (if a value was selected previously)
                        //get the existing value
                        var id = $(element).val();

                        //if a value was selected: perform an Ajax call to retrieve the text label      
                        if (id !== "") {
                            $.ajax( 
                                "accountsDataStore.xsp", {
                                    data: { id: id },
                                    dataType: "json"
                                }).done(function(data) { 
                                       // ** TODO if value not found, display current element value -- HOW??  **
                                       callback(data); });
                        }
                    }

    }).on('change', function (evt) {
                              // Do something after value changes
                              }
);
```

During `initSelection`, if the default value is not found, then **how to display the current value?**

```
<input type="hidden" 
       id="view:_id1:_id4:callback1:inputName" 
       name="view:_id1:_id4:callback1:inputName" 
       aria-required="true" 
       value="ACME Company" 
       tabindex="-1" 
       class="select2-offscreen">
```

In the form, the value is set, it just does not display in the `<span>` where a selected value appears.  Do we just add it to the list somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Dynamic option creation
>
> In addition to a prepopulated menu of options, Select2 can dynamically
>   create new options from text input by the user in the search box. This
>   feature is called "tagging". To enable tagging, set the tags option to
>   true:

look [here](https://select2.org/tagging) for detailed info

in select2 what you intend to do is called tagging and here is how it goes;

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>

//the major ish
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
});
```

in plain english just set tags during initialization of select2 and you have the option to add a value that is not in the dropdown.

hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I personally handle select2 elements that allow values not in list as follows through the proper use of a view controller (viewScoped bean).

With the following code I do 3 things:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboDemo" value="#{ctrl.comboValue}" validator="#{ctrl.validateCombo}">
   <xp:selectItems value="#{ctrl.comboChoices}" />
 </xp:comboBox>
```

1. I bind the value for the combo
2. I make sure that any new option that was created and selected client-side gets accepted
3. I load default choices for the combobox

Default choices are built keeping into account the current bound value, unless it's `null`.

```
public List<SelectItem> getComboChoices() {
    if (comboChoices == null) {
        comboChoices = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

        // Complete with your own logic here
        if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(comboValue)) {
            comboChoices.add(new SelectItem(comboValue, comboValue));
        }
    }

    return comboChoices;
}
```

Once a new value is chosen I need to make sure it will be accepted in its way back to the server. I exploit the validation phase to sneak in the new value.

```
public void validateCombo(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    boolean isNewValue = true;

    for (SelectItem item : comboChoices) {
        if (value.equals(item.getValue())) {
            isNewValue = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isNewValue) {
        String newValue = (String) value;
        comboChoices.add(new SelectItem(newValue, newValue));
    }
}
```

The above is a dumbed down version of what I do. You can make it smarter than that but I hope the example was clear enough.